# Declaring a function that takes generic input and output iterators

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to modify this function so that mimics standard library algorithms by taking input iterators and writing to an output iterator instead of what it's currently doing.

*Here is the code*:

```
template <class T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> find_combinations(std::vector<std::vector<T>> v) {
    unsigned int n = 1;
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](std::vector<T> &a){ n *= a.size(); });
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> combinations(n, std::vector<T>(v.size()));
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        unsigned int rate = n;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j != v.size(); ++j) {
            combinations[i-1][j] = v[j].front();
            rate /= v[j].size();
            if (i % rate == 0) std::rotate(v[j].begin(), v[j].begin() + 1, v[j].end());
        }
    }
    return combinations;
}
```

How it's used:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> input = { { 1, 3 }, { 6, 8 } };
std::vector<std::vector<int>> result = find_combinations(input);
```

My problem is writing the declaration. I'm assuming that it involves [iterator traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) but I haven't been able to figure out the syntax.

Comment: i don't get your question right... what do you mean by `writing it to an output iterator`? you don't want to return it? if your problem is only the declaration: `template <class T> void find_combinations(T const& in, T const& out);`

Comment: @itwasntpete the function expects iterators to nested containers and needs to know the type of the inner container. See for example `for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](std::vector<T> &a){ n *= a.size(); });`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't pass vectors by value.  A return value may be optimized and moved (even if it's nor c++11) , as an input parameter it's hard for the compiler to know if it can just pass a reference.

Second, you can't initialize a vector of vectors like that.

Now, for the syntax, just use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T>> find_combinations(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v) {

}
```

It will work fine.

Comment: The function has the flaw that it modifies the order of elements in the input vector. I'm passing by value to avoid modifying the original vector.

Comment: @A.B. So, are you asking how you can work on the return vector without extra copying ?